# Rails 3: Why isn't my Time attribute being saved to the DB correctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model with a Time attribute named `start_date`.  When I create a new object in my controller and initialize the time value, the object looks to be created correctly when I view it in the debugger...

```
(rdb:75) p @tourney
#<Tournament id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, start_date: "2011-04-22 20:05:00", duration_in_mins: 30, winners_name: nil>
```

but after it's been saved to the db, the `start_date` value is wrong and is set at the default value....

```
#<Tournament id: 5, created_at: "2011-04-22 20:07:56", updated_at: "2011-04-22 20:07:56", start_date: "2000-01-01 01:05:00", duration_in_mins: 30, winners_name: nil>
```

Here's my controller code...

```
def create

    @tourney = Tournament.new(params[:tournament]) 
    @tourney.start_date = Time.new(params[:date][:year], 
                         params[:date][:month], 
                         params[:date][:day], 
                         params[:date][:hour], 
                         params[:date][:minute])

    debugger
    if @tourney.save 
      redirect_to dashboard_path, :notice => "Tournament Created Successfully"
    else
      redirect_to dashboard_path, :notice => "Tournament Creation Failed"
    end

  end
```

Thanks so much for your wisdom!

My model code...

```
# Table name: tournaments
#
#  id               :integer         not null, primary key
#  created_at       :datetime
#  updated_at       :datetime
#  start_date       :time
#  duration_in_mins :integer
#  winners_name     :string(255)
#

class Tournament < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :participants, :dependent => :destroy

  attr_accessible :start_date, :duration_in_mins

  validates :start_date, :presence => true

end
```

Comment: the model code, as you requested

Comment: thanks. You should store start_time as `datetime` field if you want to store date as well

Comment: The Time class also has a date component, http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Time.html

Comment: In Ruby - yes. But in database - NO. You store only time in the database but Ruby returns date as well but there is no date so date is 01.01.2001

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. I got it.

You have got

```
start_date       :time
```

But you should store it as a DateTime. **So only time was stored without date!**

Plus time was saved with default offset (+0000) and not in your local timezone.

Comment: the api docs shows the Time class has a date component, http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Time.html

Comment: database doesn't,store Ruby objects but its own types

Answer (score 0):

Three things :

1) It seems that you have no attr_accessible anywhere, but bear in mind that it can cause this.

2) Try to save with save! instead of save. This will present possible model validation errors explicitly. Most times, when a model is not saved, it's because there are validation errors.

3) In your case, i would also check what Time.new(params[:tournament].... gets evaluated to, probably using rails console.

Comment: 1)I updated the model to specify accessible attributes, 2) I tried using save!, and 3) did you mean 'Tournament.new(params[:tournament])'?
Thanks again!

Comment: 3) Actually i mean something like printing out @tourney.start_date in your view, to see that it's really a valid time.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the attr_accessible :start_time in your model?

Comment: well, if he does not have it for any attribute, it cannot really cause a problem